# Using WPF DataGrid and DataTable, how can I display a deleted row using , e.g., strikethrough?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datatable

I have a C# WPF application where user can more or less directly edit a database table. I want to make user able to do multiple changes, then accept or reject the changes.

To do this, I want to display rows marked for deletion using strikethrough.

I've begun to code around it by adding an column where I mark whether the row is deleted but would prefer to use some built-in mechanism if available.

Is there an easy way to implement displaying deleted rows using WPF DataGrid and DataTable?

The issue isn't strikethrough - the issue is displaying deleted rows. The data is available in DataTable as DataRow with DataRowVersion.Original, and I want DataGrid to display the row, in the same row as it was when deleted. Implementing strikethrough format on the row I can do later.

Comment: What does make it diffcult - the fact, that the records are deleted or how to implement strikethrough?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to set a strikethrough on individual cells of the WPF DataGrid?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730839/best-way-to-set-a-strikethrough-on-individual-cells-of-the-wpf-datagrid)

Comment: Not a duplicate - I've tried to clarify the question